# Raising event from object in custom collection class

Tags: vba, events

If an object is contained within a collection, can that object still raise events to a parent class?

Clearly you could tell the child class a reference to the parent class, and then call a public method within the parent class within the child class, however that would result in a circular reference, which as I understand it would make it so the garbage collector would not ever get rid of either object.

Details:
I have two classes, one a person named clsPerson, and the second a custom collection class named clsPeople.  clsPerson has a public boolean property named Selected.  If selected is changed, I call an event SelectedChange.  At that point, I need to do something in clsPeople.  How can I trap the event in the custom collection class clsPeople?  The person class can be changed from outside of the scope of People, otherwise I would look at another solution.

```
<<Class clsPerson>>
Private pSelected as boolean

Public Event SelectedChange()

Public Property Let Selected (newVal as boolean)
  pSelected = newVal
  RaiseEvent SelectedChange
End Property

Public Property Get Selected as boolean
  Selected = pSelected
End Property

<<Class clsPeople>>
Private colPeople as Collection

' Item set as default interface by editing vba source code files
Public Property Get Item(Index As Variant) As clsPerson
  Set Item = colPeople.Item(Index)
End Property

' New Enum set to -4 to enable for ... each to work
Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
  Set NewEnum = colPeople.[_NewEnum]
End Property

' If selected changes on a person, do something
Public Sub ???_SelectedChange
  ' Do Stuff
End Sub
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can easily raise an event from a class in a collection, the problem is that there's no direct way for another class to *receive* events from multiples of the same class.

The way that your `clsPeople` would normally receive the event would be like this:

```
Dim WithEvents aPerson As clsPerson

Public Sub AddPerson(p As clsPerson)
    Set aPerson = p    ' this automagically registers p to the aPerson event-handler `
End Sub

Public Sub aPerson_SelectedChange
    ...
End Sub
```

So setting an object into any variable declared `WithEvents` automatically registers it so that it's events will be received by that variable's event handlers.  *Unfortunately*, a variable can only hold one object at a time, so any previous object in that variable also gets automatically de-registered.

The solution to this (while still avoiding the problems of reference cycles in COM) is to use a shared delegate for this.

So you make a class like this:

```
<<Class clsPersonsDelegate>>

Public Event SelectedChange

Public Sub Raise_SelectedChange
    RaiseEvent SelectedChange
End Sub
```

Now instead of raising their own event or all calling their parent (making a reference cycle), you have them all call the `SelectedChange` sub in a single instance of the delegate class.  And you have the parent/collection class receive events from this single delegate object.

**The Details**

There are a lot of technical details to work out for various cases, depending on how you may use this approach, but here are the main ones:

1. Don't have the child objects (Person) create the delegate.  Have the parent/container object (People) create the single delegate and then pass it to each child as they are added to the collection.  The child would then assign it to a local object variable, whose methods it can then call later.
2. Typically, you will want to know *which* member of your collection raised the event, so add a parameter of type `clsPerson` to the delegate Sub and the Event.  Then when the delegate Sub is called, the Person object should pass a reference to itself through this parameter, and the delegate should also pass it along to the parent through the Event.  This does not cause reference-cycle problems so long as the delegate does not save a local copy of it.
3. If you have more events that you want the parent to receive, just add more Subs and more matching Events to the same delegate class.

---

**Example Implementation**

Responding to requests for a more concrete example of "*Have the parent/container object (People) create the single delegate and then pass it to each child as they are added to the collection.*"

Here's our delegate class.  Notice that I've added the parameter for the calling child object to the method and the event.

```
<<Class clsPersonsDelegate>>

Public Event SelectedChange(obj As clsPerson)

Public Sub RaiseSelectedChange(obj As clsPerson)
    RaiseEvent SelectedChange(obj)
End Sub
```

Here's our child class (Person).  I have replaced the original event, with a public variable to hold the delegate.   I have also replaced the RaiseEvent with a call to the delegate's method for that event, passing along an object pointer to itself.

```
<<Class clsPerson>>
Private pSelected as boolean

'Public Event SelectedChange()'
' Instead of Raising an Event, we will use a delegate'
Public colDelegate As clsPersonsDelegate

Public Property Let Selected (newVal as boolean)
    pSelected = newVal
    'RaiseEvent SelectedChange'
    colDelegate.RaiseSelectedChange(Me)
End Property

Public Property Get Selected as boolean
    Selected = pSelected
End Property
```

And here's our parent/custom-collection class (People).  I have added the delegate as an object vairable WithEvents (it should be created at the same time as the collection).   I have also added an example Add method that shows setting the child objects delegate property when you add (or create) it to the collection.    You should also have a corresponding `Set item.colDelegate = Nothing` when it is removed from the collection.

```
<<Class clsPeople>>
Private colPeople as Collection
Private WithEvents colDelegate as clsPersonsDelegate

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set colPeople = New Collection
    Set colDelegate = New clsPersonsDelegate
End Sub

' Item set as default interface by editing vba source code files'
Public Property Get Item(Index As Variant) As clsPerson
    Set Item = colPeople.Item(Index)
End Property

' New Enum set to -4 to enable for ... each to work'
Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
    Set NewEnum = colPeople.[_NewEnum]
End Property

' If selected changes on any person in our collection, do something'
Public Sub colDelegate_SelectedChange(objPerson as clsPerson)
    ' Do Stuff with objPerson, (just don't make a permanent local copy)'
End Sub

' Add an item to our collection '
Public Sub Add(ExistingItem As clsPerson)
    Set ExistingItem.colDelegate = colDelegate
    colPeople.Add ExistingItem

    ' ... '
End Sub
```

Comment: This code has been extremely helpful for me. It has helped me to use interfaces and events together in VBA. Thank you for posting it! Just a couple of small corrections to it after putting it into practice: 1) The text `Raise_` can be removed from the method name in the `clsPersonsDelegate` class. 2) The `colDelegate_SelectedChange` method on `clsPeople` will need to be changed to accept a parameter of type `clsPerson`. Also, for others trying out this code, `clsPeople` will need an initialize method to `Set colPeople = New Collection` and `Set colDelegate = New clsPersonsDelegate`.

Comment: @BarrettNashville Thx!  Yes, the `Raise_` prefix is not a necessity, I just use it as a matter of style: I like to keep the names distinct so that I always know which is being referred to.

Comment: Ditto BarrettNashville's comments, extremely helpful for me too.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much!